# SQL MAX function

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing the primary key NoticeID, the NoticeDate and the notice itself. I wanted to make a query which would find the NoticeDate and notice of the row with the greatest NoticeID.
I tired this:

```
SELECT NoticeDate, Notice FROM notices WHERE NoticeID=(SELECT MAX(NoticeID))
```

It just returns the all of the rows.
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to get the `Notice` with the greatest `NoticeID` for _each_ `NoticeDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's important here is that the greatest `NoticeID` is applied to groups of `NoticeDate`, implying the need for a `GROUP BY`.

There are a few ways of approaching a query to get one full record per group (your group is `NoticeDate`).  Probably the easiest is an `IN ()` subquery which returns the `MAX(NoticeID)` per group:

```
SELECT
  NoticeDate,
  Notice
FROM
  notices
WHERE 
  NoticeID IN (SELECT MAX(NoticeID) FROM notices GROUP BY NoticeDate)
```

That may not be the fastest, however. You may also join against a subquery returning that same `MAX(NoticeID)`.  In this case, the subquery produces a table of `NoticeID` which is joined back to the full table to retrieve the remaining columns for the row it matches when joining.

```
SELECT
  n.NoticeDate,
  n.Notice
FROM
  notices n
  JOIN (
    -- Join a subquery to get the max NoticeID per group
    SELECT MAX(NoticeID) AS maxid
    FROM notices
    GROUP BY NoticeDate
) nmax ON n.NoticeID = nmax.maxid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row back, then I think the easiest approach is using `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notices n
ORDER BY NoticeId DESC
LIMIT 1;
```